# VS gives an error message saying JS isn't enabled on Firefox, even though it is (to the best of my knowledge)

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox, visual-studio-2015

I have a Lenovo running on up-to-date Windows cause god knows we don't have a choice. I recently installed VS to run simple console programs with C++ and haven't been able to do so much as "Hello World." because whenever I try to run my program, a pop-up appears that says to agree to their developer terms. I do, but then another pop-up appears that says:

Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked. To find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, or to allow scripts, see the browser's online help.

I used about:config to make sure JS was already enabled, and it was. I don't think there are any limitations. Am I maybe oversimplifying the developer agreement? Any tips/advice with IDEs in general or specifically VS is more than welcome, thanks in advance

Comment: (Temporarily) set another browser as your default browser to sign in.

Comment: VS2015, Window 10, and Firefox combo works perfectly well for signing the agreement.

Comment: @IInspectable switching to Chrome as my default worked, thanks!